# Question about timing in XNA

Tags: xna

I'm looking for a simple way to display minutes, seconds and milli seconds for timing the elapsed time in a game. Do I have to do the calculation myself with gameTime and display a variable for each part like a variable for minutes, secounds and milli seconds? Preciates some help! Thanks!

Comment: Yes I think that you can do that with TotalTimeElapsed (I think that is the name of the attribute). That value might have a subvalue that holds the entire time value (hh:mm:ss) or you can define 3 or 4 string variables and then pass values of hours, minutes and seconds like you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can already get all these three from GameTime: `gameTime.TotalGameTime` offers Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds for units to measure how long the game has been going for.

```cs
int milliseconds = gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds;
int seconds = gameTime.TotalGameTime.Seconds;
etc
```

If you just want the time since the last update, use `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime`.